# android: fragment or contextual layout in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

The question says it all.

I dont know if fragments can be included inside Navigation Drawer or not.

I am more interested to make contextual layout.
The Navigation drawer in Google play and YouTube app is not just a simple drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I dont know if fragments can be included inside Navigation Drawer or not`

Yes, they can be integrated just as in any valid part of the layout. Just put in the drawer a `ViewGroup` (FrameLayout, LinearLayout, etc) and instruct the `FragmentManager` to put a fragment in that view group by giving the layout id in `add` or `replace` method.

I am not  sure what you mean by `Contextual Layout`, but I've checked the Google Play and Youtube apps and in their drawer layout it doesn't look impossible to have fragments inside.

**EDIT**: Below is some basic example with a drawer having a fragment. I guess you know about [this developer article](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) with how to customize the drawer in conjunction with the action bar.

*drawer_main.xml*:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.left_drawer, getDrawerFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    private Fragment getDrawerFragment() {
        return new DrawerFragment();
    }
}
```

*DrawerFragment.java*:

```
public class DrawerFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {
                        "Adam", "Diana", "John"
                }));
    }
}
```

*fragment's layout drawer_fragment_layout.xml*:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_list_view"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Makes sense?

Comment: Can you put in a example code. That would simplify everything.
Your answer is something with seems to get to what I want.

Comment: Thanks just what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragment or just a layout. Navigation drawer has to child layout. First one is main, second is drawer. These two child layout can be just a layout or a fragment like youtube ext. You can find all basic information in [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).